# Not able to connect flutter socket socket_io_client 1.0.1 to nodejs server

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, websocket, socket.io

**Not able to connect websocket to the nodejs server  for websocket connection I'm using socket_io_client: ^1.0.1 library **
void connect(){

```
    IO.Socket socket = IO.io('https://MY Url', <String, dynamic>{
   'transports': ['websocket'],
   'autoConnect': false,
});
socket.connect();
socket.on('connect', (_) => print('connect: ${socket.id}'));
socket.onConnectError((data) => print(data));
socket.emit('/test', 'test');"
 print("hello");
  print(socket.connected);
  }
```

Comment: Clients have to use the `socket.on('eventName')` to listen to the events emitted by your server.

Comment: Tried this too but still socket is not connecting

Comment: Can you share your server code/documentation about the socket event that is emitted?